# Caching in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, browser, caching

I have the following problem, I have a flex application that works as a frontend in a client-server-application. In my application I have two sliders and a chart that moves when I drag the sliders, now when I have the following positions

slider 1: 10
slider 2: 20

a request is sent to the server and the response back to my flash. When I now change the sliders to

slider 1: 10
slider 2: 30

another request is sent to the server, because we have changed the position of slider 2. When I now turn the sliders again to the first position.

slider 1:  10
slider 2: 20

no request is sent to the server and the chart is moved correctly because the flash seems to know what he will receive, I think the application has cached the result. This effect only works when I open the flash application in the flash player. When I open it in the browser every slider position leeds to another request to the server. Is there a way to enable the caching also when I open it in the browser?

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

The slider values are discrete?
You can store them in an Object, and query the server only if the object[10][40] value is not set.

Comment: would be a possibility as for sure sliders are discrete given by the machine numbers ... but this is not what I want. I am interested in the integrated caching mechanism that exists.